# How to get style value to if conditions?

Tags: javascript

I want to create if function but I want put into if condition a style value for example:

```
const hello;

if (hello has display none) {
     do something
}
```

How can I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `if` is not a function, second you should find the DOM element you need to check (for example with `const element = document.getElementById('<ELEMENT-ID>');`) and then you can access to the style of the element in this way: `element.style.display`.

So:

```html
<!-- html file-->
<div id="element-to-check">
    ...
</div>
```

```js
// js code
const element = document.getElementById('element-to-check');
// To check inline style
if (element.style.display === 'none') {
   // do what you need
}

// to check css style
if (getComputedStyle(element).display === 'none') {
   // do what you need
}
```

A suggestion: try to use a more descriptive variable names instead of `hello`, also in code you write to ask help on this site.

Comment: It's working only when I specify a style in html document. If my style is in css it's not going to work

Comment: Ok it works but I have to specify elements in js not in css

Comment: If you need to check if the element is set to `display:none` by css you can use `getComputedStyle`, I'm going to update my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can access DOM element style using the `style` property.

```
const hello = document.getElementById('elementId');

if (hello.style.display === 'none') {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it...

```js
if (document.getElementById("1").style.getPropertyValue("display")==="none"){
// do something
console.log(true);
}else{
console.log(false);
};


if (document.getElementById("2").style.getPropertyValue("display")==="none"){
// do something
console.log(true);
}else{
console.log(false);
};
```

```html
<div id="1" style="display:none">TEST display1</div>
<div id="2">TEST display2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you wanna do is something like this:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('foo');

if(div.style.display === 'none'){
  alert('hello')
}else{
  // Do something else
}
```

```html
<div id="foo" style="display:none">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That all works if u specify elements in js not in css. Thnaks